# Errors in authorinfo in ACM template

Tags: errors, titles, acm

In a submission to a ACM conference with double blind review process, I'm getting errors while compiling my tex file. The error says "No authors were specified for this paper" if I try to comment out the authorinfo part. Else if I just mention

```
 \authorinfo{} Name1
            {} %Affiliation1}
            {} %Email1}
```

I get this error "File ended while scanning use of authorinfo".

How do I hide author names for this template for this paper to be ready for a double blind review process?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My guess is that you just want `\authorino{Name1}{Affilation1}{Email1}`.  But you should tell us exactly which class you are using.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I suppose you guessed right, can you write up a short answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B OK - done

Answer (score 3):

From my comment: A guess is that your are using `sigplanconf.cls` and that you usually need to write

```
\authorinfo{Name1}{Affilation1}{Email1}
```

Note that all arguments are contained within curly brackets.  To hide the author info you could write

```
\authorinfo{} %Name1}
           {} %Affilation1}
           {} %Email1}
```

so the arguments to `\authorinfo` are blank `{}`, but the auctual information is in the comments, after `%`.  A minimal document would then be:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}

\conferenceinfo{Christmas Bash 2014}{December 25, 2014, North Pole}
\doi{xx.xxx}

\begin{document}

\title{Sig Plan Yuletide}
\authorinfo{} %Name1}
           {} %Affiliation1}
           {} %Email1}
\maketitle

Main text.

\end{document}
```

In your code `Name1` is outside of the brackets, meaning the argument passing is not what you intend.  With your coding

```
\authorinfo{} Name1
            {} %Affiliation1}
            {} %Email1}
```

`\authorinfo` gets three arguments, the first from `{}` is empty, the second is `N` and the third `a`.  The rest `me1` starts producing printed output, but does not produce an error.  I suspect you have written something like

```
\authorinfo{ %Name1}
            {} %Affiliation1}
            {} %Email1}
```

with one of the opening brackets `{` not matched by an uncommented closing bracket, which does produce the reported error message.